# Kotlin fun() vs lambda is there difference?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, anonymous-function

This question is about fun() vs a lambda block definitions and scopes.
i have tried define the expressions in two ways.   Here is what i have tried:

```
  val myFunction = fun(){
    println("i am in a function")
    }

//but i also tried doing this:

    val myFunction = {
    println("i am in a lambda")
    }
```

my problem is i do not know if they are equivalent and  same thing ?

Comment: I believe `return` inside the body behaves differently. Like, in the first case, it'll be a return from `myFunction`, while in the second 1) in your current code you can't use return 2) As an argument to functions accepting lambdas it'll be a return from outer function. Also I suspect that first case disables inlining when passed as an argument.

Comment: @dyuhka please do not speculate. You can use links (for example to the language reference) to provide prove for your points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences are best described in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions:

1. Anonymous functions allow you to specify return type, lambdas don't.
2. If you don't, return type inference works like for normal functions, and not like for lambdas.
3. As @dyukha said, the meaning of `return` is different:

   > A return statement without a label always returns from the function declared with the fun keyword. This means that a return inside a lambda expression will return from the enclosing function, whereas a return inside an anonymous function will return from the anonymous function itself.
4. There is no implicit `it` parameter, or destructuring.

Your specific cases will be equivalent, yes.

Answer (score 1):

See the reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

> There are several ways to obtain an instance of a function type:
>
> Using a code block within a function literal, in one of the forms:
>
> - a lambda expression: { a, b -> a + b },
> - an anonymous function: fun(s: String): Int { return s.toIntOrNull() ?: 0 }

Both give you a function object which can be used interchangeably